# NS3 - python.h file can not be located compilation error

Tags: python, c++, compiler-errors, header

I have included Python.h in my module header file and it was built successfully.

Somehow when I enabled-examples configuration to compile the example.cc file, which includes the module header file. It reported the Python.h file can not be found - fatal error.

I have no clue at the moment what is being wrong.

Could anyone give a hint? It is for the NS3(Network Simulator 3) framework.

Comment: Could you please provide the locations of both the files.

Comment: I have another question if you are still interested: I tried to call a python function from C++ using pFunc=PyDict_GetItemString(pDict,functionname); Whatever I tried, it always return pounce = NULL. Have you done anything similar before? Thanks.

Comment: I've not tried python with ns3 yet. In the future, I plan to do reinforcement in ns3.

Comment: Sounds good. Keep me posted of your work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for writing back to me:).

I solved the issue by adding the pyembed feature in the wscript within the same folder as my.cc file.

Thanks again:).

J.